# Binding custom list object properties to textbox from code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

**Student class**

```
public class Student
{
    string name;        

    List<SubjectInfo> subjectInfoList;        

    ....
}
```

`List<SubjectInfo>` List can have different number of `SubjectInfo` objects for different students.

**SubjectInfo class**

```
public class SubjectInfo
{
    string subjectCode;

    int marks;

    ...
}
```

I want to display student object detail on a window. Since **List** have different number of object count I generated these from code behind.

```
int i = 10;

        foreach (SubjectInfo info in student.SubjectInfoList)
        {
            TextBox tb = new TextBox();
            tb.Width = 200;
            tb.Height = 20;
            tb.Margin = new Thickness(10, i, 0, 0);
            StudentDataGrid.Children.Add(tb);
            i += 60;
        }
```

I would like to bind this **List** list from code behind. But I have no idea of doing that.
I want to bind **marks** property of `student.SubjectInfoList`

Please help me with binding list object properties from codebehind.

**EDIT**
This is the sample student object;

```
Student student = new Student("Joe", new List<SubjectInfo>() { new SubjectInfo("Subject1", 50), new SubjectInfo("Subject2", 70)});
```

My window should like this;
[image]

**NOTE** if student doing 4 subjects total `TextBox` count is 5.

Comment: What are you using, WPF or Winforms?

Comment: WPF and I want to make bindings from code behind.

Comment: Why do you want it to be from code behind? And what controls do you bind to?

Comment: Because `List<SubjectInfo>` count can have different count for different student. Window is going to display the student information. I want to bind **marks** property to textboxes. For an example if a given student doing 5 subjects `List<SubjectInfo>` count is 5. I want to generate 5 textboxes and display the marks on that textbox

Comment: Then you can do it all in XAML.

Comment: If my approach is bad, please guide me.

Comment: OMG please don't instantiate or manipulate WPF controls in code behind. That's the devil himself. Better show a picture of what you want to achieve and we can teach you the XAML way.

Comment: @HighCore I've tried, but too late.

Comment: @HighCore- Ok. I will upload an image how I want to look like my window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pure XAML solution:

```
<Window  (... your window attributes) >

    ....

    <Grid x:Name="StudentDataGrid">
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SubjectInfoList}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SubjectInfo}">
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Marks}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

But to have it work you have to transform your fields to public properties:

```
public class Student
{
    string name;        

    public List<SubjectInfo> SubjectInfoList { get; set; }

    ....
}
```

and:

```
public class SubjectInfo
{
    string subjectCode;

    public int Marks { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

#### UPDATE

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">


    <Grid x:Name="StudentGrid">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Text="Student name :" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Student marks :" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"/>

        <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" />

        <ListView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding SubjectInfoList}" BorderThickness="0">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SubjectInfo}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding SubjectCode}"/>
                        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Marks}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Student student = new Student("Joe", new List<SubjectInfo>() { new SubjectInfo("Subject1", 50), new SubjectInfo("Subject2", 70) });
            StudentGrid.DataContext = student;
        }
    }

    public class Student
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<SubjectInfo> SubjectInfoList { get; set; }

        public Student(string name, List<SubjectInfo> list)
        {
            Name = name;
            SubjectInfoList = list;
        }
    }

    public class SubjectInfo
    {
        public string SubjectCode { get; set; }
        public int Marks { get; set; }

        public SubjectInfo(string subjectCode, int marks)
        {
            SubjectCode = subjectCode;
            Marks = marks;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why I did not choose a `ListView` is,since this window is like a form. :(

Comment: @NewDeveloper I've updated my post. If you have any question ask me. But now I have to go home ;).

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I will definitely ask question if I have issue. :)

Answer (score 1):

Better to do it in XAML.
But if you really want to do it in code-behind, try this.
Fields of SubjectInfo must be public.

```
foreach (SubjectInfo info in student.SubjectInfoList)
{
   TextBox tb = new TextBox();
   ///...
   tb.DataContext = info;
   Binding binding = new Binding("marks");
   tb.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, binding);
   ///...
}
```

Comment: @NewDeveloper bad idea but OK. It solves your problem but it is not the correct way to do with WPF and data binding.